# What is the difference between ionic cap sync and npx cap sync?

Tags: ionic-framework, npx

I used to build Ionic application and I'm used to `ionic cap sync` when I make changes in my code. Recently, I used `npx cap sync` instead and it is a lot faster but sometimes it feels like it just ignore all the changes I've made. When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ionic cap sync` first builds (ie `ionic build`) before doing the same as `npx cap sync`

> ionic capacitor sync will do the following:
>
> - Perform an Ionic build, which compiles web assets
> - Copy web assets to Capacitor native platform(s)
> - Update Capacitor native platform(s) and dependencies
> - Install any discovered Capacitor or Cordova plugins

Source: https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/capacitor-sync

> Capacitor CLI - cap sync
> This command runs copy and then update.

Source: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/cli/sync

Answer (score 2):

npx cap sync, copies only web assets in "web" folder to the native folder.
ionic cap sync, build and copies everything (dependencies, assets) the app requires to the native folder.